# selectively hide webpart on homepage

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, custom-list, page-layout

My homepage has an embedded view of a list called Project Info which displays important project information. One of the fields is a choice field called `ProjectStatus` which can read either Pending, Active or Awaiting Approval. I want to selectively hide and display a pair of promoted links web-parts depending on the currently displayed contents of the Choice field.

I managed to accomplish something similar with hidden LVWPs based on another choice field called `ProjectPhase` using the code below but this method will not allow for a range of choices:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var ProjectPhase = document.querySelector("table[summary='Project Info Log ']").innerText.match(/Phase [1-9]/g)[0]

switch(ProjectPhase) {
case "Phase 1":
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ10").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ11").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ12").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ13").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7").style.display = 'none';
break;
case "Phase 2":
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ9").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ11").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ12").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ13").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7").style.display = 'none';
break;
case "Phase 3":
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ9").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ10").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ12").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ13").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7").style.display = 'none';
break;
case "Phase 4":
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ9").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ10").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ11").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ13").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7").style.display = 'none';
break;
case "Phase 5":
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ9").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ10").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ11").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ12").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6").style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
```

Can anyone suggest how I can modify this to work with a choice field with the following options: Pending, Active, Awaiting Approval, On Hold, Cancelled, Completed?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your choice field with the options you mentioned is same as `ProjectPhase` or different? Also you want to merge the conditions of two choice fields or just add conditions for your second choice field and remove conditions of `ProjectPhase`?

Comment: The choice fields are different. ProjectPhase has conditions Phase 1, Phase 2, Phase 3, etc. I want to accomplish the same effect as the above code (hide webparts based on field contents) for a different set of conditions

Answer (score 1):

Assuming display name of your choice field is "Project Status" and it is drop-down, you can try something like given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ProjectStatus = document.querySelector("select[title^='Project Status']").value;

    switch(ProjectStatus) {
        case "Pending":
            document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1").style.display = 'none';
            break;
        case "Active":
            document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2").style.display = 'none';
            break;
        case "Awaiting Approval":
            document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3").style.display = 'none';
            break;
        case "On Hold":
            document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4").style.display = 'none';
            break;
        case "Cancelled":
            document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5").style.display = 'none';
            break;
        case "Completed":
            document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6").style.display = 'none';
            break;
    }
</script>
```

You can add multiple hide/show statements inside each case statement as per your requirements.

Comment: Looks promising but currently throws the following error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference. I've checked and the list name and webpart ID are definitely corrent.

Comment: This is because of the wrong selector used to get the Project Status value. Can you please click inspect element on your Project Status drop-down, take a screenshot and add it to your question, then I will help you to get the correct selector for your Project Status field.

Comment: images added. the html is split across 2 pics

Comment: Are you doing it on SharePoint form or somewhere else?

Comment: Try using this: `var ProjectStatus = document.querySelector("table[summary='Project Info Log ']").innerText.match(/ProjectStatus [1-9]/g)[0] `.

Comment: Now I get this error in the console: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

Comment: ok, I guess this is a custom solution and definitely the issue is with Project Status selector. From screenshots it is nor clear how you have created this control. Try using this: `var ProjectStatus = document.querySelector("table[summary='Project Info Log ']").innerText.match(/Status [1-9]/g)[0]`.

Comment: No Joy. It is a custom page with an embedded Data View of the Project Info Log list.
The code you just suggested is identical to the code that worked to select the contents of the ProjectPhase field. I'm not sure why that snippet works and this one deos

Comment: So this line: var ProjectStatus = document.querySelector("table[summary='Project Info Log ']").innerText.match(/Active/g)[0]. captures the word Active as a variable how can I expand this to include the other column choices.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the answer. The variable needs to be told to look for an array of possible answers, not just one. The code looks like this:

```
var ProjectPhase = document.querySelector("table[summary='Project Info Log ']").innerText.match(/(Pending|Active|On Hold|Cancelled)/)[0]
```